# Why isn't my canvas working with 2 particles?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have a codepen: http://goo.gl/jatUZC and I want to combine 2 particle effects onto one webpage. Only one particle canvas is showing.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be one overlays the other. I can see that you set confetti's `z-index` to be behind the other one.

Mistake! That other one seems to have a black background which will cover everything else.

Meanwhile if you invert the roles, #confetti's background covers the top one.

What to do? make #confetti z-index 0 and remove background.

Fork: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeJeRq